# How to maintain and extend Drupal based site?

Tags: drupal-7

I've just released a simple Drupal based site on a hosting partner.

The development was done by, first running a install script provided by my hosting partner. The script installed a default Drupal site eith a database.
After this I just logged in to my site and used admin tools to configure my site.

If that was step one,, step two will be to extend my site with one or two extra functions and improve look and feel.

My question is,,, how do I do that without interfering with my site witch now is "live"?

Are there some established methods and tools for doing this??

/regards
/lg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on what you want to do and how you have your site set up so far. If you have one page that is set as frontpage, then you can make another page and test your new functions on that one. Or you could install another site, set it up in a similar way and try it there first.

There's of course loads of ways to do everything. You can start searching for "drupal deployment workflow" and go from there.

Comment: Tanks. That a correct search term was really all I needed. I did not know where to start.